# Setting up Play 2.0 project with Sql Server 2005

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2005, playframework, playframework-2.0

I previously had my app set up to use a MySQL db as the default, and it worked fine.

Now I'm trying to get it to work with ***SQL server 2005***. The I tried this and several similar variants:

### application.conf

```
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlserver://remoteServerName:Port"
db.default.driver=com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
db.default.user=correctUser
db.default.pass=correctPass
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Driver not found: [com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver]
...
caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
```

At first glance, it seems like this would hint the jdbc driver JAR is missing from the build path. The problem is, it *isn't* missing from the build path. sqljdbc4.jar is sitting in the build path with everything else.

Am I missing something? I'm not sure where to go here.

Comment: JDBC drivers are dynamically loaded and not compiled in, so it being in the build path doesn't necessarily mean it gets deployed with the application. Can you verify that it's in your classpath when running the application?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson How would I do that? I looked into the java.class.path property but it just returns a JAR file in my play directory

Comment: make sure you have ran the command `play eclipsify` after `play clean`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the error seems to indicate it hasn't loaded your jar properly. There are two possible solutions.

1. You need to add it to your build.scala file.

   ```
   val appDependencies = Seq(
       "sqljdbc4" % "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "3.0"
   )
   ```
2. Or you could add it the a lib folder in the root project folder.

Comment: To add on ali's comment, it does not work as microsoft do not expose their jar. Download the jar and add it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `lib` folder at the root of you Play app, and then put your `sqljdbc4.jar` file under this `lib` folder.

sbt will add this folder and the contained jars in your classpath, and the `dist` task will add the jar on the generated zip.

Comment: Please open your jar file and check if it is a valid jar.